# UITableViewCell memory management

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

Pretty basic cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation.

I'm wondering why the analyzer is telling me that i'm leaking memory here.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyObject *object = [[self.datasource objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = object.title;

    return cell;
}
```

the analyzer tells me that 'cell' is potentially leaking. Is this just a weakness in the analyzer or how am i supposed to handle this?

note: adding a call to autorelease like so:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

causes a crash. Any thoughts?

Comment: inside your `if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }` your alloc/init without autorealease see if that helps out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using ARC, then you should autorelease the cell:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Note that this is **not equivalent** with autoreleasing it after retrieving it from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, because that method is called multiple times for a particular cell, and over-autoreleasing causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the autorelease on the line where you alloc new cells:

```
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```